# How to update records using select records of the same table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following sample table

```
Mat_ID     Prod_ID     QTY
--------------------------
100        20          50
101        20          60
100        21          0
101        21          2
100        22          0
101        22          1
101        23          8
```

I want to update the QTY of all Prod_ID != 20 with the QTY of Prod_ID 20 of the same Mat_ID.

So for my example, the table should be like this I execute the query.

```
Mat_ID     Prod_ID     QTY
--------------------------
100        20          50
101        20          60
100        21          50
101        21          60
100        22          50
101        22          60
101        23          60
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `update`.  Here is a method uses a correlated subquery:

```
update t
    set qty = (select t2.qty
               from t t2
               where t2.mat_id = t.mat_id and
                     t2.prod_id = 20
              )
    where prod_id <> 20;
```

Note:  this assumes that you there is exactly one row for each `mat_id` for `prod_id = 20`.  If you can have multiple rows, you can use aggregation in the subquery:

```
update t
    set qty = (select sum(t2.qty)
               from t t2
               where t2.mat_id = t.mat_id and 
                     t2.prod_id = 20
              )
    where prod_id <> 20;
```

Comment: Thank you. It works perfectly.
Would it be possible to do an insert as well? Like if Prod_ID 20 has Mat_ID 103 and Prod_ID 33 doesn't have Mat_ID 103, is there a way to combine update and insert?

Comment: @Franco . . . That is a very different question; ask a *new* question with sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below -

```
UPDATE t SET t.QTY= (SELECT t1.QTY
                                  FROM t1
                                  WHERE t1.mat_id = t.mat_id and t1.Prod_ID=20)
WHERE t.Prod_ID!=20
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use merge for it as follows:

```
SQL> create table my_tab as
  2  SELECT 100 as Mat_ID, 20 as Prod_ID , 50 as QTY from dual union all
  3  SELECT 101, 20, 60 from dual union all
  4  SELECT 100, 21, 0  from dual union all
  5  SELECT 101, 21, 2  from dual union all
  6  SELECT 100, 22, 0  from dual union all
  7  SELECT 101, 22, 1  from dual union all
  8  SELECT 101, 23, 8  from dual ;

Table created.

SQL> merge into my_tab m
  2  using (select * from my_tab
  3  where PROD_ID = 20) t
  4  on (m.Mat_ID = t.Mat_ID and m.PROD_ID <> 20)
  5  when matched then
  6  update set m.QTY = t.qty;

5 rows merged.

SQL> select * from my_tab;

    MAT_ID    PROD_ID        QTY
---------- ---------- ----------
       100         20         50
       101         20         60
       100         21         50
       101         21         60
       100         22         50
       101         22         60
       101         23         60

7 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Cheers!!