# How to update, insert delete records from records of the same table

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to update, insert and delete records from records of the same table.

Sample Table

```
Mat_ID   Prod_ID   QTY
----------------------
100      20        50
101      20        60
102      20        50
100      21        0
102      21        0
100      22        10
103      22        20
```

For the table above, I would like to update all QTY of all Mat_ID with Prod_ID != 20. At the same time, insert all Mat_ID of Prod_ID 20 to all Prod_ID that doesn't have the Mat_ID. Same with delete. Delete all Mat_ID not on Prod_ID 20.

Output

```
Mat_ID   Prod_ID   QTY
----------------------
100      20        50
101      20        60
102      20        50
100      21        50
101      21        60
102      21        50
100      22        50
101      22        60
102      22        50
```

This is an addition to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58166095/how-to-update-records-using-select-records-of-the-same-table/58167262#58167262)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the non-matching values using `cross join` to generate the rows and then `left join` or a similar mechanism to filter out the values that exist.  The complete table would be:

```
select m.mat_id, p.prod_id, m.qty
from (select distinct mat_id, qty
      from t
      where prod_id = 20
     ) m cross join
     (select distinct prod_id
      from t
     ) p ;
```

This is probably the simplest way to create the table you want.  But if you want to insert the missing rows (your actual question):

```
select m.mat_id, p.prod_id, m.qty
from (select distinct mat_id, qty
      from t
      where prod_id = 20
     ) m cross join
     (select distinct prod_id
      from t
     ) p left join
     t
     on t.mat_id = m.mat_id and t.prod_id = p.prod_id
where t.mat_id is null;
```

Comment: I've modified the second code to work with my requirements and I'm using it to select Mat_IDs available on Prod_ID 20 and insert to all Prod_IDs that doesn't have the Mat_IDs.

Could you help me select all Mat_IDs present in all Prod_IDs not 20 and is missing in Prod_20. I would use it to delete those extra Mat_IDs that are not in Prod_ID 20.

Thanks.

Comment: @Franco . . . Why not just use the first query?  You can save the results in a temporary table, then truncate the original table, and insert the rows into the table all at once.